# Improve circle detection with opencv on Go Board

Tags: java, opencv, geometry, detect, hough-transform

I have to detect all the stones on the board but I have some problems with the HoughCircle algorithm. If I reduce too much the param2 then also the space between the lines of  the grid shows up as circles, and I don't know how to solve this.

How can I detect the stones with more precision?
The HoughCircle use canny to detect a circle, but there are no circles within the lines of the board, so I don't understand.
I don't think I could use a filter by color because the color of the white stones and the board are similar in some places.

This is the image I work with.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab9Di.jpg

I know that the light isn't really good, but I want to know if it's possible anyway.

And this is what I got until now.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGTyF.png

That's the code that I made:

```
        Mat circles = new Mat(undistorted.size(), CV_8UC3);

        Mat toGrayScaleForHough = undistorted.clone();

        Imgproc.cvtColor(toGrayScaleForHough, toGrayScaleForHough, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2BGR);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(toGrayScaleForHough, toGrayScaleForHough, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 0);

        Imgproc.dilate(toGrayScaleForHough, toGrayScaleForHough, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_CROSS, new Size(3, 3)));
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(toGrayScaleForHough, toGrayScaleForHough, new Size(13, 13), 2, 2 );

        HoughCircles(toGrayScaleForHough, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 45, 30, 20, 30, 50);

        stones = new ArrayList<Stone>();

        Imgproc.cvtColor(undistorted, undistorted, COLOR_HSV2BGR);
        for(int i = 0; i < circles.cols(); i++){
            Rect circleROI = new Rect((int)circles.get(0, i)[0]-6, (int)circles.get(0, i)[1]-6, 36, 36);

            Mat ROI = new Mat(undistorted, circleROI);

            Scalar color = mean(ROI);


            int x, y;
            x = (int)Math.round((circles.get(0, i)[0] - 40) / 100);
            y = (int)Math.round((circles.get(0, i)[1] - 50) / 100);

            if(color.val[0] < 90){
                stones.add(new Stone(new Point(x,y),new Scalar(0,0,0)));
                circle(undistorted, new Point(circles.get(0, i)[0], circles.get(0,i)[1]),(int)circles.get(0, i)[2], new Scalar(89, 255, 202),15);
            }else {
                stones.add(new Stone(new Point(x,y),new Scalar(255,255,255)));
                circle(undistorted, new Point(circles.get(0, i)[0], circles.get(0,i)[1]),(int)circles.get(0, i)[2], new Scalar(89, 255, 202),15);
            }
        }
```